# Getting count of Ethereum transactions per day

Tags: transactions, ether, json-rpc, infura, chaindata

I’m trying to write a call to get count of eth transactions per day, without using a pro api subscription. Anyone has some ideas about how to achieve this, maybe using an infuria.io project api?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try `getBlockTransactionCountByNumber` RPC method to get the number of transactions in a block. You can query Infura (or any other RPC provider) for each block that's been minted and create an aggregate. Or you can also get  other block details too, like timestamp using `getBlockByNumber` method. It contains the list of all the transactions included in that block.

You can get the latest block using `blockNumber` method. So you can periodically call it to get the latest block, and get the transaction count till that block.